# What is the actual use case of using eval in production? If we need to query the DB, we can directly access it. Why would someone go to sqoop?

Tags: sqoop

I would like to know the importance of eval in sqoop. As per the command, we can query the remote database through sqoop. But I would like know real use case of it specially in production as I don't see any.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `sqoop eval` tool is for *evaluation purpose only*.

As per sqoop [documentation](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_purpose_11):

> **Warning**
>
> The eval tool is provided for evaluation purpose only. You can use it to verify database connection from within the Sqoop or to test simple queries. It’s not suppose to be used in production workflows.

Regarding use case of `eval`:

You can preview the result of SQL queries on the console. This will help the developer to preview sqoop import queries.

Answer (score 0):

Sqoop eval is used to verify established connection database and preview query result.

sqoop eval --connect "connection_url" --username *** --password**   --query "select count() from Table_name"

Don't use in prod environment not a good practice.

Its just to verify your connection